# Unrelated image being displayed during sharing link in facebook

Tags: facebook, image

I have a website. When anyone shares a link of my website(manually and not by Graph API), an incorrect image is being displayed rather than the logo of my website. Please tell me how to display the logo correctly. Is there a meta tag or something like that to do that thing...Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special meta property for displaying the correct image. Some of them are as follows :-

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/url?dynamic=0 />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/your-logo.png" />
```

You can find every detail at the [Open Graph Website](http://ogp.me)